# Creating customized bar chart in android

Tags: android, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I want to create a customized bar chart as per the below screenshot
[image]

Here we have a custom tooltip, custom gridlines, clicking left or right arrow will load the next or previous set of data. Also, B and T in the tooltips are the values we need to show on the bar as a marker. Can we build the same kind of graph with any library out there like [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) etc or Should I go with my own implementation for this set of the graph?